# Calligra font with RMarkdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown

This is my Rmarkdown code:

```
---
title: "My Title"
header-includes:
      - \usepackage{calligra}
      - \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
output:
  pdf_document:
  latex_engine: xelatex 


---

# Section 1

  This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:
```

I was studying the best way to change fonts in Rmarkdown. In texlive the installed calligra package appears and calligra-type1 also.

When I run the script with the calligra package it generates the pdf but the font does not match the calligra font.

And when I run the script for calligra-type1  the pdf is not even generated.

Any help, guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `calligra.sty` does not set-up the Calligra as default font, but you can do so by adding

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{calligra}
```

to `header-includes`.

BTW, there is no need to call `fontenc.sty`, since `calligra.sty` does so already. In addition, using `xelatex` is not necessary here.